# html - Select default tab inside pagination for list item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-lists, jquery-pagination

```
<div>
    <pagination ng-show="ready"
                total-items="total"
                ng-model="index"
                ng-change="func()"
                class="pagination-sm"
                boundary-links="true"
                items-per-page="1"
                max-size="15">
    </pagination>
    <ul class = "active">
        <li><a>val1</a></li>
        <li><a>val2</a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="o in values"> <a>{{o.val}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are a set of tabs displayed in each pagination. The default tab (`val1`) is selected on page1. Say I change the tab to `val2` or something else from the ng-repeat. And I goto page2 (currently nothing is selected). There how can I make `val1` selected?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like below:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="o in values" heading="{{o.title}}" active="o.active">      
        <a>{{o.val}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $scope.active = function() {
        return $scope.o.filter(function(o){
          return o.active;
        })[0];
    };
</script>
```